# Multiplying two 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, matrix-multiplication

so I am having an issue multiplying two 2d arrays together.  I am pretty sure that matrixA and matrixB are being stored properly, they are displayed properly when the program is ran.  When I try to multiply the 2 arrays together I am getting a long string of a lot of 1's and 0's.  Any idea on what could be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/* Routines called. */
int loadMatrixFromFile(char *filename, int *data);
void showMatrix(int *data, int len);
int makeIdent(int matrixB[5][5], int length);
int matrixA[5][5];
int matrixB[5][5];
int matrixC[5][5];
void multiplyMatrices(int matrixA[5][5], int matrixB[5][5],int matrixC[5][5]);

int main(){
    int len, data[1000];
    len = loadMatrixFromFile("Numbers.txt", data);
    showMatrix(data, len);
    makeIdent(matrixB,len);
    multiplyMatrices(matrixA, matrixB, matrixC);
}

int makeIdent(int matrixB[5][5], int len)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Matrix B = \n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
           for(j=0;j<5;j++){
                 if(i==j){
                         matrixB[i][j]=1;
                         printf("%d ",matrixB[i][j]);
                 }
                 else{
                     matrixB[i][j]=0;
                     printf("%d ",matrixB[i][j]);
                 }
           }
           printf("\n");
     }
    return matrixB[i][j];
     printf("\n");
}
int loadMatrixFromFile(char *filename, int *data)
{
    FILE *in;
    int len;
    int j;
    in = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (in == NULL) {
        printf("Could not find file: %s \n", filename);
    }
    else {
        printf("Reading numbers...\n");
        fscanf(in, "%d", &len);
        printf("reading %d numbers from file %s ....\n", len, filename);
        for(j=0;j<len;j++) {
            fscanf(in, "%d", data + j);
        }
        fclose(in);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                matrixA[i][j] = *data;
        }
    }
    return len;
}
void showMatrix(int *data, int len)
{
    int j;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Showing %d numbers from data array....\n", len);
    printf("Matrix A = \n");
    for(j=0;j<len;j++) {
        printf("%d ", *(data + j));
        count++;
        if(count % 5 == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void multiplyMatrices(int matrixA[5][5], int matrixB[5][5],int matrixC[5][5]){
     int i, n, j;

         printf("\n");
 printf("Matrix A x Matrix B = \n");
 for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
    for (n = 0; n<5; n++){
        for (j = 0; j<5; j++){
            matrixC[i][n] += matrixA[i][j]*matrixB[j][n];
            printf("%d ",matrixC[i][n]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how the text file looks that the array A is being pulled from:

```
25 

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 1
2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 1 2
3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: With simulated input, it seems to be working okay to me. [check this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a330bff6138045cd)

Comment: Thats weird.  In the console mine shows: Matrix A x Matrix B = 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1  0 1 1 1 1 1.......

Comment: I think you need to initialize `matrixC` to zeros, before you start multiplication. Also, don't print in the loop of multiplication, unless its for debug. Print it using `showMatrix()` as you do for others.

Comment: Seems something wrong here: `matrixA[i][j] = *data;`

Comment: It appears that you are writing C code, not C++ code, as you have included `<stdio.h>` instead of `<cstdio>`. If you are indeed writing C code, you should **not** include `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems something wrong here:

`matrixA[i][j] = *data;`

You should use

`matrixA[i][j] = *(data + i*5 + j);`

Also, try printing:

`printf("%d ",matrixC[i][n]);`

inside second loop `n` (after innermost loop `j`).

Comment: That helped a little bit 0xF1 :).  The output I am getting now is Matrix A x Matrix B = (next line) 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 6 7 0 0 0 6 7 8 0 0 6 7 8 9 0 6 7 8 9 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 3 0 0.......  It seems there is a pattern where the numbers are being icremented for some reason.

Comment: So it is working sort of but not really lol.  I got it to show the array breaking the line after every 5 numbers.  So it is printing out 1 0 0 0 0 (\n) 0 2 0 0 0 (\n) 0 0 3 0 0 (\n) 0 0 0 4 0  (\n) 0 0 0 0 5 (\n) 6 0 0 0 0 (\n) 0 7 0 0 0.....  It is multiplying each number in matrixA by the identity matrix and then displaying all of them instead of just replacing the 1's in the identity matrix(matrixB) with the value in matrixA.

Comment: Well, are you sure your arithmetic is correct?  Because the increment would mean you're multiplying the diagonal of your identity against the rows of A.  What is your intended output?

Comment: @Chemistpp My arithmetic must be off because I am not meaning for it to create a new row upon every times it increments in i.  I am looking for more of the index in each matrix to multiply only itself on the other matrix.  Working on it now.

Comment: @Shawn delete one of the nested loops in multiply, and change the line to `matrixC[i][j] = matrixA[i][j]*matrixB[i][j];`

Comment: @Chemistpp If I could make love to you I would.  Thank you works perfect and thank everybody else for the help.